# Identifier not found in variables and functions with arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, identifier

I'm using VS ultimate 2012, and trying to make a class but all variables and functions that have a parameter keep returning "identifier not found".

The functions update(), run(), etc. work perfectly fine.

I tried defining, e.g: mIsMovingUp(false) and Game::mIsMovingUp in the .cpp file but neither worked, and I'm really stuck here.

Errors:

```
game.cpp(24): error C2039: 'handlePlayerInput' : is not a member of 'Game'
game.h(7) : see declaration of 'Game'
game.cpp(27): error C2065: 'mIsMovingUp' : undeclared identifier
game.cpp(29): error C2065: 'mIsMovingDown' : undeclared identifier
game.cpp(31): error C2065: 'mIsMovingLeft' : undeclared identifier
game.cpp(33): error C2065: 'IsMovingRight' : undeclared identifier
game.cpp(62): error C2065: 'mIsMovingUp' : undeclared identifier
game.cpp(64): error C2065: 'mIsMovingDown' : undeclared identifier
game.cpp(66): error C2065: 'mIsMovingLeft' : undeclared identifier
game.cpp(68): error C2065: 'mIsMovingRight' : undeclared identifier
```

Code:

```
//game.h
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Game
{
    public:
        Game();
        void run();

    private:
        void processEvents();
        void handlePlayerInput(sf::Keyboard::Key key, bool isPressed);
        void update();
        void render();

    private:
        sf::RenderWindow mWindow;
        sf::CircleShape mPlayer;

        bool mIsMovingUp;
        bool mIsMovingDown;
        bool mIsMovingRight;
        bool mIsMovingLeft;


};

#endif
```

.

```
//game.cpp
#include "..\Headers\game.h"

Game::Game()
    : mWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Beginning")
    , mPlayer()


{
    mPlayer.setRadius(40.f);
    mPlayer.setPosition(100.f, 100.f);
    mPlayer.setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);
}

void Game::run()
{
    while (mWindow.isOpen())
    {
        processEvents();
        update();
        render();
    }
}

void Game::handlePlayerInput(sf::Keyboard::Key key, bool isPressed) //error
{
    if (key == sf::Keyboard::W)
        mIsMovingUp = isPressed;               //error
    else if (key == sf::Keyboard::S)
        mIsMovingDown = isPressed;             //error
    else if (key == sf::Keyboard::A)
        mIsMovingLeft = isPressed;             //error
    else if (key == sf::Keyboard::D)
        IsMovingRight = isPressed;             //error
}

void Game::processEvents()
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (mWindow.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
            handlePlayerInput(event.key.code, true);
            break;
        case sf::Event::KeyReleased:
            handlePlayerInput(event.key.code, false);
            break;
        case sf::Event::Closed:
            mWindow.close();
            break;
        }
    }
}

void Game::update()
{
    sf::Vector2f movement(0.f, 0.f);

    if (mIsMovingUp)                   //error
        movement.y -= 1.f;
    if (mIsMovingDown)                 //error
        movement.y += 1.f;
    if (mIsMovingLeft)                 //error
        movement.x -= 1.f;
    if (mIsMovingRight)                //error
        movement.x += 1.f;

    mPlayer.move(movement);
}

void Game::render()
{
    mWindow.clear();
    mWindow.draw(mPlayer);
    mWindow.display();
}
```

.

```
//main.cpp
#include "game.h"

int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.run();
}
```

Comment: I think you need to include `SFML/Window.hpp` in `game.h` to be able to use `sf::Keyboard`.

Comment: That's not it, and it doesn't explain the variables. https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML-Game-Development-Book/blob/master/01_Intro/Include/Book/Game.hpp The original writer of this code didn't include keyboard or window

Comment: One error is `IsMovingRight = isPressed;` is missing the `m` in front.  Not that it helps much.

Comment: shouldn't you include `game.cpp` in main?

Comment: No, I don't think you should ever include a .cpp file in a header. Either way it didn't work

Comment: @TriHard8 You don't include `cpp` files.

Comment: @Matt McNabb You're a genius, it worked. I don't know why the program worked up until now

Comment: @JoeDefill ok, glad you got it solved. Have converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include "..\Headers\game.h"` is suspicious. You should have `#include "game.h"` and have your include paths set up properly.

Perhaps it is actually including an old version of the file that doesn't have those things defined in class Game.

To test this you could put some garbage into game.h and see if it causes `game.cpp` to give a compiler error